# Updating NetworkFirewall::FirewallPolicy with AWS-managed rules in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Currently my stack is an LZA which creates its own Network Firewall, and associated empty Network Firewall Policy called "LZAFirewallPolicy".

Through a CF template, I want to import AWS-managed rules into the empty policy. To do this, I have tried creating a Policy with the same resource name (LZAFirewallPolicy) with the desired rules. However, I'm running into an issue where it can't create the resource as the name already exists (Obvious issue, I know).

Not sure how to proceed, if I should create a new policy and somehow have the current Network Firewall 'point' to the new policy. However I'm unsure how to achieve this in CloudFormation.

Please find my code below:

```
Resources:
  FirewallPolicy:
    Type: AWS::NetworkFirewall::FirewallPolicy
    Properties:
      FirewallPolicyName: LZAFirewallPolicy
      FirewallPolicy:
        StatefulEngineOptions: 
          RuleOrder: 'DEFAULT_ACTION_ORDER'
        StatelessDefaultActions:
          - 'aws:forward_to_sfe'
        StatelessFragmentDefaultActions:
          - 'aws:forward_to_sfe'
        StatefulRuleGroupReferences:
          # [30000/30000 rules] 
          - ResourceArn: !Ref AbusedLegitMalwareDomainsActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref MalwareDomainsActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref BotNetCommandAndControlDomainsActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesBotnetActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesBotnetWebActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesBotnetWindowsActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesDoSActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesEmergingEventsActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesExploitsActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesIOCActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesMalwareActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesMalwareCoinminingActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesMalwareMobileActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesMalwareWebActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesPhishingActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesScannersActionOrderRuleGroup
          # ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesSuspectActionOrderRuleGroup
          - ResourceArn: !Ref ThreatSignaturesWebAttacksActionOrderRuleGroup
```